# ¿Cómo comparar password_hash generado en php con JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Tengo un campo en mi base de datos el cual guarda contraseña de usuario y lo  encripta al retornarlo ¡con una función get php. Este es el código en php:

```
  function getAccion(){
            // cifrando la contraseña
        return password_hash($this->db->real_escape_string($this->accion_pass),PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost' => 4]);
        }
```

Necesito comparar esa contraseña que retorno en php con js, la contraseña encriptada la tomo a partir de un select en el cual tengo un atributo donde asigno ese valor de esa contraseña. Con este código tomo el valor que imprimo en php en cada select distinto:

```
let pass_x=$('#numm>option:selected').attr("data-x");
```

En esta parte necesito comparar lo que el usuario ingresa en el input, con el valor del select que esta encriptado, tengo este código para comparar lo que el usuario ingresa en el input:

```
  let dato_ingresado = $('#input_daton').val();
          if(pass_x == dato_ingresado) {
             //código a ejecutar
           }
```

Pero no se como comparar el hash que genero php con js, saludos espero me orienten

Comment: Las contraseñas deberían verificarse en el servidor, no en el cliente.

Comment: Tal como bien [comenta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375901/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-password-hash-generado-en-php-con-javascript#comment674482_375901) @ACedano, las contraseñas se deben comparar (validar) del lado servidor y no del lado cliente. El potencial riesgo de seguridad (que pueden explotar) al intentar hacerlo como planteas es que estás devolviendo al cliente el `hash` almacenado en DB, si bien es difícil intentar descifrar la clave mediante fuerza bruta, es muy fácil buscar la misma en una [tabla arcoiris](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_arcoíris). Saludos

Comment: Hola un saludo la contraseña, que quiero compara es solo para confirmar un proceso sencillo, por ejemplo mlas contraseñas las requiero para  confirmar una acción ya que no es nada relacionado con usuarios, solo es para aceptar un proceso que realizo en un determinado campo, por ejemplo tomo datos en un modal donde lleno inputs que son solo de datos para realizar un procesos sencillo, ya que solo es para estar seguro que el usuario quiere hacer la solicitud de ese servicio, no compromete el login del sistema, un saludo

Comment: "Tengo un campo en mi base de datos el cual guarda contraseña de usuario y lo encripta al retornarlo ¡con una función get php", en tu anterior comentario indicas que no es una contraseña relacionada con usuarios, estas contradiciendote amigo, ten en cuenta lo que te dice tu amigo A. Cedano y porfavor escuchalo, porque el tiene mucha razon al decir eso, es algo muy muy peligroso hacer la validacion desde el frontend, en vez de eso debes comparar la contraseña en el backend, aunque si decides omitir nuestras alertas que no te extrañe que puedan hackear facilmente la BD.

Comment: si lose, lo que quiero hacer es algo similar a el botón de aceptar los termino pero para una acción en especifico aprobando con una contraseña x solo es para aceptar un servicio que esta al publico el usuario ni siquiera se los usuarios hacen login, saludos, quizás plante mal el código php por tomar un código de la parte de usuarios, lo corregí, ya tomo el password de la parte de acciones, nada que ver con el login del sistema saludos